# Altium Issue: PCB Switch Pad Nets for Rubber Button

Tags: pcb, switches, altium, eda

I am currently trying to create a component in Altium for a rubber keypad switch. This will be like the ones in TV remotes etc where there are a mesh of fingers connected when the conductive pill makes contacts with both sides.

Having read the following [design guide](http://www.endrich.de/cms/download.php?file=716/34219.pdf&name=Silicone%20Rubber%20Keypads%20-%20Design%20Guide), I have come up with a PCB pattern

The issue I'm having is when I place this component on the PCB. The nets for both sides of the component only show one net:

[image]

There is a clearance issue on the left is where the pin has been placed and the nets colliding.

Any suggestions for solutions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In your PCB footprint pattern you need to make sure that each side has its own pad and number. If you name the pads for each side of the switch using the same designator, they will appear as being on the same net. It doesn't look like you used pads at all, though. When you create a component like this you need to start with an actual pad, then draw traces extending from it (this is all in the PCB footprint library). You seem to have just traces.

Comment: The different nets definitely have their own pads. In the picture shown, the pads are the same size as the tracks but definitely there.
I have tried making the pads wider than the tracks with no success. I have also tried recreating the component; the pad was placed first then its respective track.

Comment: The pad size should not matter to the program but it will when a surface material is applied

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you have the connection pads for the two component terminals nearly on top of each other. One would have to be moved so that it is intersecting with the added copper associated with the other switch connection.

Comment: The pads are on their separate sides on the library component. The net associated with the pad on the right(pad 2) has been transferred to the track on the left. The clearance issue is with pad 1 and the track.

Comment: Well, clearly something is not associated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The footprint was being placed upon a board which already had tracks upon it. The tracks which crossed the PCB component caused the nets to be incorrectly assigned.